# C++ When inputting, program ends without continuing

Tags: c++

EDIT: Here is the If-Else. Please see what is going on. And can someone tell me how to return if the answer is wrong? Like, INcorrect answer, enter again?

using namespace std;

```
int main()
{

cout<<"Welcome to the Grade Database. Please insert your domain: " ;
cout<<"\n";
int d, n;
cin>>d;
cout<<"Now enter your total grade(between 0-100): " ;
cin>>n;
if (n>0 && n<59){
    cout<<"See you next year then :(" ;
    cout<<"F-"<<n;}
else if (n<60 && n>=69){
    cout<<"Well...you pass ;D" ;
    cout<<"E-"<<n<<"  ~"<<d;}
else if (n>70 && n<=79){
    cout<<"Better than the average!";
        cout<<"D-"<<n<<"  ~"<<d ;}
else if (n>80 && n<=89){
    cout<<"Very well sir!";
    cout<<"C-"<<n<<"  ~"<<d;}
else if (n>90 && n<=99){
    cout<<"Wow, amazing! One of the best!";
    cout<<"B-"<<n<<"  ~"<<d;}
else if(n==100){
    cout<<"Well, hello there Mr. Stephen Hawking.";
    cout<<"A-"<<n<<"  ~"<<d;}
else{
    cout<<"Invalid Entry.";}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `switch` can't use conditions (it compiles because the condition is just an expression, and expressions are allowed as statements -- but it's not actually doing anything) -- show us how you were you doing it with if-else.

Comment: I edited. What do you think?

Comment: Ok, still not working :( Even with endl;

Comment: Check your second condition -- no number can ever be both less than 60 and greater than 69 at once ;-) Also, look at the boundary conditions: for example, `n > 90` means "is n *strictly greater* than 90", which for integers means 91 and up -- but the previous class only accounts for numbers up to and including 89 -- so an input of 90 will fall into the final "invalid input" `else` clause. Finally: Keep at it, it gets easier and more fun the more you learn :-)

Answer (score 5):

`switch` in C++ doesn't support ranges or conditions, only exact matches.  Since you have conditions, try using `if` and `else`, like this:

```
cin>>n;
if (n>0 && n<59) {
    cout<<"See you next year then :(" ;
    cout<<"F-"<<n;
}
else if (n>=60 && n<=69) {
    cout<<"Well...you pass ;D" ;
    cout<<"E-"<<n<<"  ~"<<d;
}
else if (n>=70 && n<=79) {
    cout<<"Better than the average!";
    cout<<"D-"<<n<<"  ~"<<d ;
}
else if (n>=80 && n<=89) {
    cout<<"Very well sir!";
    cout<<"C-"<<n<<"  ~"<<d;
}
else if (n>=90 && n<=99) {
    cout<<"Wow, amazing! One of the best!";
    cout<<"B-"<<n<<"  ~"<<d;
}
else if (n==100) {
    cout<<"Well, hello there Mr. Stephen Hawking.";
    cout<<"A-"<<n<<"  ~"<<d;
}
else {
    cout<<"Invalid Entry.";
}
```

You probably also want some newline characters.  Simply writing `cout <<` a second time won't start a new line, have a look at `std::endl`.

Comment: Umm, I know I can use the "using namespace std;" for cout/cin. But thanks for the advice ;3